# Automatic trigger not working when new data imported through script in other spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

### Problem

I have the following script. What it does when triggered manually is :

- Creating new sheets with the name of each person in column A
- Adding a row in the newly created sheet with the data of columns A and B
- Other stuff with no impact on the problem below

When I set the built-in trigger, it simply doesn't work.

### What I already tested

What is important to know in my opinion is that the data in column A and B in this spreadsheet is imported thanks to another script in another spreadsheet. Why is it important ? Because if I set a built-in trigger on change or edit and I add a row manually, it triggers my built-in trigger as perfectly as when I trigger it manually.

### Conditions

Last thing to explain, I don't want a "solution" that forces me to make a manual action to make it work. I need it to work automatically, not with some kind of checkbox or something.

Does anyone could have a solution for this problem ?
A huge thanks in advance to help me solve this issue.

### Code

```
function createNewSheets() {
  // 1. Retrieve the current sheet names.
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = dataSheet.getSheets().map(s => s.getSheetName());

  // 2. Retrieve the values from "mastersheet" sheet.
  var masterSheet = dataSheet.getSheetByName('Liste de nageurs');
  var values = masterSheet.getRange('A2:B' + masterSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // Imports table from link
  var swimmerTable = '=IMPORTHTML(B1;"table";4)'
  // Concatenates event with pool size
  var fullName = 'CONCATENATE(C2;" - ";D2)'

  // 3. Using the retrieved sheet names and values, the new sheets are inserted and the values are put.
  values.forEach(r => {
    if (!sheetNames.includes(r[0])) {
      var newSheet = dataSheet.insertSheet(r[0])
      sheetNames.push(r[0]);
      newSheet.appendRow(r);

      // Sets the formula in the 3rd column:
      newSheet.getRange(1, 3).setFormula(swimmerTable)

      // Sets the formula2 and iterates it from row 2 to row 50
      newSheet.getRange("J2:J50").setFormula(fullName)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry but onEdit and onChange triggers only respond to user edits they don't respond to changes by other scripts or formulas.  You can use time based triggers to run scripts periodically or use clientside setTime or setInterval but that requires clientside to remain active.  So I don't think there is a workaround for what you want.

Comment: @Bastien Soret Can I ask you about your situation? 1. About `What is important to know in my opinion is that the data in column A and B in this spreadsheet is imported thanks to another script in another spreadsheet.`, can you provide this current script? 2. What is the script of `createNewSheets()`?

Comment: @Bastien Soret I think that if the script which puts the values to Spreadsheet is created using Spreadsheet service with `SpreadsheetApp`, as a workaround, when the script is used with Sheets API, OnChange trigger can be used. Or, as another workaround, I think that when the script for putting to Spreadsheet is run, the another function you want to run can be run by the running function. So I asked about the script for putting the values to Spreadsheet. By confirming your script, I would like to propose the modified script.

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal as follows.

- You have 2 Spreadsheets "A" and "B", and each Spreadsheet has the container-bound script.
- The script of Spreadsheet "A" is as follows.

  ```
    function exportDataNageurs() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var values = ss.getSheetByName('Nageurs').getRange('A2:B').getValues();
      var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###");
      var targetSheet = dataSheet.getSheetByName("Liste de nageurs");
      targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  ```
- The Spreadsheet "B" has the script of `createNewSheets()` in your question.
- **When the script `exportDataNageurs()` of Spreadsheet "A" is run and the values are put to Spreadsheet "B", you want to automatically run the script `createNewSheets()` of Spreadsheet "B".**
- You want to achieve this using the trigger.

### Issue and workaround:

When I saw your script of `exportDataNageurs()`, the values are put using [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) with SpreadsheetApp. In this case, unfortunately, even when the values are put to the Spreadsheet "B", the OnChange trigger is not fired. This is the current specification at Google side.

In order to fire the OnChange trigger when the values are put to the Spreadsheet "B" using the script, I would like to put the values using Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service. By this, when the values are put to the Spreadsheet "B" using Sheets API, the OnChange trigger can be fired.

### Usage:

#### 1. Modified script of Spreadsheet "A".

Please modify `exportDataNageurs()` as follows. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the Spreadsheet ID.

```
function exportDataNageurs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName('Nageurs').getRange('A2:B').getValues();
  var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: values}, spreadsheetId, "'Liste de nageurs'!A2", {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

#### 2. Install OnChange trigger to Spreadsheet "B".

Please install the OnChange trigger to the function `createNewSheets()` at Spreadsheet "B". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

#### 3. Testing.

After the OnChange trigger was installed to `createNewSheets()` at Spreadsheet "B", please run the script `exportDataNageurs()` at Spreadsheet "A". By this, the values are put to the sheet "Liste de nageurs" of Spreadsheet "B" and run the script `createNewSheets()`.

I thought that in your script `createNewSheets()`, the event object might not be required to be used.

### Note:

- As another method, I think that using the Web Apps which was deployed to Spreadsheet "B", when `exportDataNageurs()` is run, your goal can be also achieved by requesting from the script `exportDataNageurs()` to the Web Apps. Also, the function can be also run using Google Apps Script API. But I thought that above method using Sheets API might be simpler and suitable for your situation. So I proposed it.

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: You rocked it once again. Thank you for helping all along. I tested all my workflow again from my registering and entering data in the app and seeing the result almost instantly within it. I can scale it easily now that I don't have manual actions to do anymore, I can focus on design and features :) Thanks again for your great help !

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand about your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.